# sed does not render parameter value

Tags: linux, string, amazon-web-services, sed, user-data

I have a scenario where i need to generate and update values of secret key at runtime and update my configuration files. The value of fernet key doesn't seem to render and it is getting replaced by string `$fernet_key` itself. Have tried Within `"" {} ()` . Nothing seems to be working. Please advise.

```
fernet_key="$(python3 -c 'from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; print(Fernet.generate_key().decode())')"
sed -i -e 's|{FERNET_KEY}|$fernet_key|g' ~/config.yml
```

I am doing similar for secret key though with `echo` which is working perfectly though.

```
secret_key="$(python3 -c 'from base64 import b64encode;import os; print(b64encode(os.urandom(64)).decode())')"
echo -e "SECRET_KEY=$secret_key" > ~/.env
```

Comment: Use double quotes, `"s|{FERNET_KEY}|$fernet_key|g"`. What is the value of `$fernet_key`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fernet key is random string. But i have tried with test value like 'abcd' . that did not work too.

Comment: " seem to have done the magic. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. "s|{FERNET_KEY}|$fernet_key|g" worked.